# Networkx: For a new path, find the closest path in a given list of paths

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I have a list of paths like [P1-P3-P4-P6, P1-P2-P3, P3-P5-P6-P7]. And a new path, P1-P5-P3. Here its closest path would be P1-P2-P3, since by just changing the second element, I can get the same path. Can I do this using NetworkX?

Also, if I had a path in my list like P1-P5-P3-P7, and the test path being P1-P5-P3, is it possible to have a fast lookup for any subpath of an existing path, in this case it would return P1-P5-P3-P7.

Comment: I think you've got a typo on the closest path.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit the algorithm of choosing the closest paths? Do you choose the closest path based only on nodes (i.e. the closest path will have the biggest number of matching nodes)?

Comment: can you edit it?  `P1-P3-P3` doesn't look right.  I assume you mean `P1-P2-P3`, but don't want to edit it for you.